# How do you validate a datatype in umbraco?

Tags: umbraco

I've created a custom data type in umbraco and I would like to check the value before it is saved and provide error messages if it is not ok.

How do you enforce validation rules on a data type?

Answer (score 0):

have you consider using `ValidationProperty` for this purpose?

Once you added the attribute, you can implement the property by adding your validation logic. This way you can make sure about data validation before you user save the record with new custom datatype.

E.g

```
 [ValidationProperty("HasValidValue")]
    public partial class MyDataEditor : System.Web.UI.UserControl,
        umbraco.editorControls.userControlGrapper.IUsercontrolDataEditor
```

In your Custom datatype logic and then has something like following....

```
public string HasValidValue
        {
            get
            {
                if (CheckIfDataIsValid())
                    return "Valid";
                else
                    return String.Empty;
            }
        }
```

This way you can do it at code level.

Thanks,
Jigar

Comment: Hi, I was aware of this, however it does not allow you to give an error message to the user. I don't recall now, but I think there are other gotchas with using this, like you would have to make it mandatory in the UI.

Comment: Yes that is true you need to it mandatory and also with some validation controls.

Comment: what do you mean "with some validation controls"?